# DAX Sum(Value) based on Previous calculation Months

Tags: powerpivot, dax

HI all I'm trying to create a % variance for Budget to Actuals, While I can do this I'm getting an issue with the rollup. Actual data is complete July-October Budget is for the Complete Year (Fiscal)

So using 
Actual:=Calculate(Sum([Actual]),Version[VersionID]=1,Filter(DimTime,[Year]=2015)) 
I get the total by month with Quarter / Year rollup for the Actuals

For Budget I want the same thing however I can't get it filtered to only Sum the Same time period of the actuals. SO the Year and Quarter rollup I always receive the Whole year/quarter data.

Wrong
Time    Actual  Budget  VTB

**2015  566913  1667972 194%**

**Q1    400863  399702  0%**

Jul 131092  137071  5%

Aug 126736  127712  1%

Sep 143035  134920  -6%

**Q2    166050  393531  137%**

Oct 166050  142959  -14%

Correct
Time    Actual  Budget  VTB

**2015  566913  542661  194%**

**Q1    400863  399702  0%**

Jul 131092  137071  5%

Aug 126736  127712  1%

Sep 143035  134920  -6%

**Q2    166050  142959  137%**

Oct 166050  142959  -14%

I can capture the Max(TimeID) as it relates to the actuals in this case 201410 as a value.

Budget:=Calculate(Sum([Budget]),Version[VersionID]=1,Filter(DimTime,[Year]=2015))
Would Like
Budget:=Calculate(Sum([Budget]),Version[VersionID]=1,Filter(DimTime,[TIMID]<= Max(TIMEID))

I just can't seem to apply it to the sum of Budget values

Thanks

Phil

Comment: Can you elaborate with your data model? What are tables involved and what columns do they have?

Comment: You have Budgets by Month?

Answer (score 0):

Using following technique you can see above required Report, Only caveat here is that you would be able to see rows for either Year or Quarter or Month.

Assuming you have Budgets by Month. You will have to create a new table for "Month" with these columns (MonthName,MonthNumber,Year). Add a calculated column in your DimTime to refer to appropriate row in newly created Month table. Also relate your Budget table to this newly created Month table.

Now when you use this Month.MonthName on Rows in PivotTable, you should see desired result.